# Is there an official or safe way to use a LetsEncrypt certificate for the WHM UI?

Tags: https, cpanel, security-certificate, whm, lets-encrypt

To be specific, I am talking about using a LetsEncrypt (LE) cert for WHM *itself*, not a domain being managed by these tools.

I'm well aware that I could install [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) and reconfigure the underlying web server by hand, but generally, I'm averse to doing this as I could see the changes being trivially overwritten at some point by WHM or cPanel (or flagged by a security addon). For instance, when I used WHM's *change hostname* function, a new certificate **signed by cPanel Inc** was automatically installed.

I'm already using the [LetsEncrypt AutoSSL plugin](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enabling-lets-encrypt-for-autossl-on-whm-based-servers/), but it explicitly calls out:

> The Let’s Encrypt™ provider plugin does not generate hostname certificates for your system’s services. It only generates SSL certificates for your cPanel accounts.

#### Configuration

- The server's hostname is `web1.example.com`
- WHM is accessed from either `whm.example.com` or `web1.example.com:2087`. Either of these access methods presents a cPanel Inc. signed certificate for `web1.example.com`
- The underlying server is a VPS I have root access to.
- The server is authoritative for its own DNS (that is, `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` and `whm.example.com`) all point to the same IP on the same VM.
- `example.com` has a cPanel account in WHM
- `cpanel.example.com` points at this account and uses the AutoSSL LE certificate

One note: The underlying server's CPanel/WHM was migrated from a shared hosting arrangement by the webhost's technical support team, so there may be vagaries in its configuration that are non-standard.

Basically, I want to stay within WHM's "happy path" if at all possible. If not, and I need to make changes behind its back to make this work, that's fine too.

---

In summary: **What is the right way to get WHM to use a LE certificate?**

Comment: Could you add a cPanel account for `whm.example.com` so that AutoSSL could fetch the certificate?  Then I'd think it would just be a matter of symlinks.

Comment: @MikeCiffone: This is an AutoSSL for older versions of WHM and doesn't appear to be relevant to the problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Tried it; doing so breaks access to WHM (in that `whm.example.com` stops pointing to it and starts pointing to a new account skeleton). I deleted it with no issue, and did see that AutoSSL did get a LE cert.

Comment: @MikeyT.K. You're right I misunderstood, but also yeah outdated. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat new plug-in named [FleetSSL](https://cpanel.fleetssl.com/docs/for-admins/service-certificates/) explicitly offers the ability to request and install LE certificates for cPanel services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Supporting information as follows: this plug-in exists and directly solves the problem as I described it. It was linked to. No further information is relevant or necessary.